# Vim keep last line at bottom of buffer

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling

I need to configure Vim in such a way that it has a normal scrolloff of 3 or 5. But in such a way that it keeps the last line at the bottom of the screen. I don't want that as I scroll, the last lines of the buffer to come up to the top of the screen under any circumstance.
To make this more precise I want this:

[image]

and no matter what key I press, I explicitly do not want this:

[image]

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Can you put some images where this happens?

Comment: Press `G`, followed by `ctrl-f`. I think this is what he is talking about.

Comment: Exactly, what @Vitor said

Comment: Try if setting the 'scrolloff' option helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try scrolling when you are at the bottom vim assumes you want to move the text up.

You can replace commands like `ctrl-f` with an additional "move cursor to bottom of screen" using `zb`. This modification would need to be added to any other commands you wish this to not occur.

`:nnoremap <c-f> <c-f>zb`

Now when you `ctrl-f` at the bottom of the screen it stays at the bottom, but so does every instance of `ctrl-f`.

**Update**

If you would like to do it conditionally you'll need to write a little function that compares your current position to the end of the file.

```
function! NoScrollAtEOF()
  let curpos = getpos('.')
  let lnum = get(curpos, 1, -1)
  let len = line('$')
  if lnum + winheight(0) >= len 
    normal! zb
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <c-f> <c-f>:call NoScrollAtEOF()<cr>
```

This function pulls the current position and the end of file position and calls `zb` if the current position plus the height of your window is greater than the end of file...if you can see the end of the file in your window.

Comment: Thanks! I undestand the approach. How would I conditionally do this only if the cursor in on the last n lines of the buffer?

Comment: Using the function I provided in the updated answer should keep the scrolling to operate as normal until you get close to the end. If you wish it to be `n` lines rather than the window height then replace the function with your value.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to write a function to toggle `scrolloff` between your desired amount (3 or 5) and 999 depending on how many lines are left in the document versus your window height. something like, `(lines in document) - (line of cursor) <= (lines in window)`.